# In Powershell how can I check if all items from one array exist in a second array?

Tags: arrays, powershell

So let's say I have this array:

```
$requiredFruit= @("apple","pear","nectarine","grape")
```

And I'm given a second array called `$fruitIHave`.  How can I check that `$fruitIHave` has everything in `$requiredFruit`.  It doesn't matter if there are more items in `$fruitIHave` just as long as everything in `$requiredFruit` is there.

I know I could just iterate over the list, but that seems inefficient, is there a built-in method for doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do you try Compare-Object :

```
$requiredFruit= @("apple","pear","nectarine","grape")
$HaveFruit= @("apple","pin","nectarine","grape")
Compare-Object $requiredFruit $haveFruit
InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
pin                                                         =>
pear                                                        <=

Compare-Object $requiredFruit $haveFruit | where {$_.sideindicator -eq "<="} | % {$_.inputobject}
pear
```

Comment: Same without requiring where filter:   Compare-Object $requiredFruit $HaveFruit -PassThru -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual

Comment: @Dirk Won't work, this will return the intersection of $requiredFruit and $haveFruit, instead of the complement of $haveFruit in $requiredFruit.
This however would work: `$requiredFruit.Where{$_ -notin $haveFruit}`

Answer (score 17):

If you have the arrays:

```
$requiredFruit= @("apple","pear","nectarine","grape")
$someFruit= @("apple","banana","pear","nectarine","orange","grape")
$moreFruit= @("apple","banana","nectarine","grape")
```

You can get a boolean result with:

```
'Check $someFruit for $requiredFruit'
-not @($requiredFruit| where {$someFruit -notcontains $_}).Count

'Check $moreFruit for $requiredFruit'
-not @($requiredFruit| where {$moreFruit -notcontains $_}).Count
```

Using the count of an array protects against a single value not matching that evaluates as False. For example:

```
# Incorrect result
-not (0| where {(1,2) -notcontains $_})

# Correct result
-not @(0| where {(1,2) -notcontains $_}).Count
```

With PowerShell v3, you can use `select -first 1` to stop the pipeline when the first mismatch is found (in v2 `select -first 1` allows only one object through, but previous elements of the pipeline continue to process).

```
-not @($requiredFruit| where {$moreFruit -notcontains $_}| select -first 1).Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly "builtin" but:

```
[regex] $RF_regex = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($requiredFruit |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’

($fruitIHave -match $RF_regex).count -eq $requiredFruit.count
```

That creates an alternating regex from the elements of $requiredFruit.  Matched against $fruitIHave, it will return all the items that matched.  If $fruitIhave could potentially have duplicates of the same fruit you may need to run that match result through get-unique before you do the count.  It may be slower than iterating over the list for a single comparison, but once you have the regex built it will do repetitive matches very efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

One way or the other, you're going to have to iterate through one or both arrays.  Here's a one-liner approach:

```
$hasAllRequiredFruit = ($requiredFruit | Where-Object { $fruitIHave -contains $_ }).Length -eq $requiredFruit.Length;
```

A `foreach` loop would be better because you can stop iterating as soon as you find a required fruit that is missing:

```
$hasAllRequiredFruit = $true;
foreach ($f in $requiredFruit)
{
    if ($fruitIHave -notcontains $f)
    {
       $hasAllRequiredFruit = $false;

       break;
    }
}
```