# Issue with comparing two collections of blobs in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I have a powershell script that pulls down files from Azure blob storage into a local folder. Once it has pulled a file down it creates a 0 byte file with the same name, but with the .succeeded extension (eg foo.csv becomes foo.csv.succeeded). Both the original file and the .succeeded file stay on the blob storage.

I want to modify my script so that files that have a .succeeded counterpart are not re-downloaded when the script is run again. I am trying to compare 2 sets of blobs to this end, but I cannot get it to work. Here is a snippet of the code I have:

```
$ext = '.succeeded'

$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -sasToken $sasToken -StorageAccountName $accountname        
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $blob_source_container -Context $ctx  

# Get list of all blobs from specified folder with the '.succeeded' extension
$succeeded = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $blob_source_container -Context $ctx | 
    Where-Object { (($_.Name -like "$blob_source_folder*") -or ($blob_source_folder -eq '*')) -and ($_.Name -like "*$sidecar_extension") }

# Strip the extension from the blob names ending in '.succeeded'
foreach($blob in $succeeded) {
    $blob.Name = $blob.Name.Substring(0, $blob.Name.LastIndexOf('.'))
}

foreach($blob in $blobs) {
    if($blob.Name -notlike "*$ext"){
        if($blob.Name -notin $succeeded | Select Name) {
            # do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If I place a Write-Output $blob.Name inside the do stuff statement, it prints all blobs that can be downloaded, regardless of whether or not they are in $succeeded.

I have been at this for most of the day and I am about to give up. Am I missing anything basic?

Comment: What is in  $sidecar_extension ($_.Name -like "*$sidecar_extension")? Should this be $ext?

Comment: Yes. My mistake. The code snippet in my question was ‘simplified’. In the actual script it’s $sidecar_extension. In the example it’s $ext

Answer (score 0):

Your query to get only the succeeded does not appear to be correct. A quick stab at it is below, but Write-Output the contents of both $blobs and $succeeded to see where you are going wrong. If your container is huge, make a test one with only a few files in it to debug.

Try replacing

```
# Get list of all blobs from specified folder with the '.succeeded' extension
$succeeded = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $blob_source_container -Context $ctx | 
    Where-Object { (($_.Name -like "$blob_source_folder*") -or ($blob_source_folder -eq '*')) -and ($_.Name -like "*$sidecar_extension") }
```

with

```
# Get list of all blobs from specified folder with the '.succeeded' extension
$succeeded = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $blob_source_container -blob *.succeeded -Context $ctx | 
    Where-Object { (($_.Name -like "$blob_source_folder*") -or ($blob_source_folder -eq '*')) -and ($_.Name -like "*$sidecar_extension") }
```

i.e. adding `-blob *.succeeded` to your $succeeded query.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can confirm that the $succeeded variable contains all the values it should - A list of all filenames that have the .succeeded extension, but with the extension removed.

Comment: Must be an issue with your comparison. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815192/in-powershell-how-can-i-check-if-all-items-from-one-array-exist-in-a-second-arra

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this myself this morning (after not looking at the code for several hours!)

I simply replaced:

```
if($blob.Name -notin $succeeded | Select Name) {
```

With:

```
if($blob.Name -notin $succeeded.Name) {
```

and it worked a treat.